# Why $f$ must be monotone-decreasing function on integral test?

Tags: calculus

From proof of integral test, used this :
$$f(n)\leq f(x) \leq f(n+1)$$
and integrate all of them and sum it.when $$n<x<n+1$$

But I think monotone-decrease doesn't need if function $f$ satisfies :
$$0<f(n)\leq f(x) \leq f(n+1) \quad \forall n \in\mathbb{N}$$

So, is there any counterexample for function $f$ which satisfies
$$0<f(n)\leq f(x) \leq f(n+1) \quad \forall n \in\mathbb{N}$$
but
$$\sum f(n) <\infty \nleftrightarrow \int f(x)dx<\infty$$
?

Comment: Are you requiring that $$0<f(n)\leq f(x) \leq f(n+1) \quad \forall n \in\mathbb{N}$$ holds for solely $n<x<n+1$ or for *all* $x$?

Comment: @macton $x\in [n, n+1], f(n) \leq f(x) \leq f(n+1) \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you wanted to write $$f\left(n\right)\color{red}{\geq}f\left(x\right) \color{red}{\geq} f\left(n+1\right).$$

You are right, this inequality is enough for proving integral test.